# Change displayed text in the Like box

Tags: facebook-likebox

I am looking to change the name of the Facebook page that is displayed as part of the Facebook "like" box.  The entity name is very long so I want to put a nickname on there to save space on the web page.  Is there a way to make that change or does it have to match the name on the actual Facebook page it is linking to?  I am using the iframe code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the name of your Facebook Page as displayed in the [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). It dynamically loads your Page's true name, and there are no override parameters.

If your Page has fewer than 100 Likes you can [change the name of your page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=271607792873806#How-do-I-change-my-Page-name?-) to something shorter.

If you really need to, you could probably change the name in the Box with some clever JavaScript (but that *won't* work with the iFrame code - cross domain security errors).